# Semaphores and fork() in C

Tags: c, fork, semaphore

I have the following block of code :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "display.h"

int main()
{
  int i;

  if (fork())
  {
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
      display("ab");
    wait(NULL);
  }
  else
  {
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
      display("cd\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Where display.c is :

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!!!  */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "display.h"

void display(char *str)
{
  char *p;
  for (p=str; *p; p++)
  {
    write(1, p, 1);
    usleep(100);
  }
}
```

and display.h is :

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE!!!  */

#ifndef __CEID_OS_DISPLAY_H__
#define __CEID_OS_DISPLAY_H__
void display(char *);
#endif
```

If i run this code the output is :

```
abacdb
abcdab
acdbababa
cbadb
cad
bcd
cd
cd
cd
cd
```

I want to use semaphores in order to have an output like this :

```
abcd
abcd
abcd
....
```

My attempt to do this is the following :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "display.h"
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{


    int i, my_sem, v1,v2,t;

    my_sem = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, 0600);   /* CREATE OF THE SEMAPHORES */

    struct sembuf up = {0, 1, 0};       
    struct sembuf down = {0, -1, 0};    

    if (fork())
        {

            for (i=0;i<10;i++){

                display("ab");
            semop(my_sem, &up, 1);      /* UP (); */

            wait(NULL);

            }

        }
        else
        {
            for (i=0;i<10;i++){
            semop(my_sem, &down, 1);    /* DOWN (); */

                display("cd\n");

            semop(my_sem, &up, 1);  /* UP (); */
            }


        }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of my code is :

```
abcd
cd
cd
cd
cd
cd
cd
cd
cd
cd
ababababababababab
```

It seems that it works only for the first time. I am very new into sempaphores so i need some help in order to make my code work.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Aren't semaphores for multi-thread sync, rather than multi-process?

Comment: @EugeneSh. From the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview): `POSIX semaphores allow processes and threads to synchronize their actions.`.

Comment: Well my professor wants to find a solution to this problem using semaphores. His question was very clear. Is it impossible to use them for multi-process? @EugeneSh.

Comment: As @EnzoFerber is pointing, it should be fine.. Rusty on this stuff.

Comment: @ArisKantas It also seems you're using an old semaphone API. From the manual link I posted: `System V semaphores (semget(2), semop(2), etc.) are an older semaphore API. POSIX semaphores provide a simpler, and better designed interface than System V semaphores; on the other hand POSIX semaphores are less widely available (especially on older systems) than System V semaphores.`. Are there restrictions about what API you should be using?

Comment: In the loop in the parent, you wait(NULL), which means that the first iteration will pause until the child terminates. That seems consistent with the result. Why is that surprising?

Comment: Oh yes. In fact he teaches us about System V semaphores. I learned about POSIX semaphores only when I came back home form university and searched the web. So it is mandatory that we have to use System V semaphores. @EnzoFerber

Comment: Why is this happening only once thought? @rici

Comment: @arisKantas: You should look at the documentation for what wait() does. Once the child has finished, the parent has no more children, so wait() won't do anything. Maybe you think wait() has something to do with the semaphore. It doesn't. When the child is done, it is done done done. If you wait for the child to finish, you wait for the child to finish. It doesn't come back to life and do more stuff after that.

Comment: @rici I did what you said an hour ago and learned about wait() so thank you very much. Do you think that the use of the wait() on my code makes it work incorrect?

Comment: @ArisKantas: Yes. There are other problems with your code, but it is definitely incorrect for the parent to wait until the child has completely finished. Or at least, that won't do what you want to do. Either the output will be as you see it, or the two processes will https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock

Comment: @rici Ok. So where do you think after i remove wait, that i should UP() and DOWN() my semaphore in order to have the correct result! I am asking something so specific because i want to fully understand the use of semaphores. And because my thoughts are not working I am afraid I haven't understand everything perfectly about their use. Maybe an example with my code will help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wait(null)` waits for the child process to terminate, in this case you're waiting for the child to completely finish before resuming your "ab" loop, hence why "ab" is displayed once followed by all "cd" lines.

You need to think further about how to communicate between processes. You can use your semaphores (their values) to prevent one process from making progress while allowing another to make progress.

Comment: I think you helped me understand a little bit more about semaphores.

Comment: It would be very helpfull if you show me an example thought. @brettkc Thank you.